# script redirect in php is recursive

Tags: javascript, php

Sorry:- another rank new-be! My code is placed on both mobile and desktop pages so as to redirect to the relevant page. However this seems to cause a recursive recall with the web page trying to reload over and over. Do I need to exit; Any other options? As i said don't seem to be able to use headers.

```
<?php $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android...etc)
{echo '<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://mobile.tebb.com.au/"
</script>';}
else
{echo '<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.tebb.com.au/"
</script>'; }
?>
```

Comment: are you missing the end of `if(preg_match('/(android...etc)`?

Comment: you never bothered checking if you're ALREADY on the proper site, so if someone comes in as (say) Android, they redirect to mobile. mobile checks if they're on mobile, and hey! they are, so redirect to mobile... you need `If (mobile && (not already on mobile site))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android...etc)
header ('http://example.com/');
?>
```

Try this

I find that the header method is way more efficient and reliable as opposed to doing window.location

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I had not checked if already on the page.